# Webapp works on my windows dev box but not on server which is running Debian

Tags: mysql, unix

I have a web application based on a mysql database.

It works fine locally but not on the unix machine.

I have tried looking at the Tomcat logs but they don't seem to have any errors.

How would you go about trying to debug this. I know it' possible that there are no answers. I am just hoping that someone had a similar problem, can post a fix that just might work for me.

I am asking for issues to consider rather than solutions. So the obvious ones are:

- Have you pointed to the correct server
- Did you use the correct username and password
- Check the port
- Check that mysql has been started

Or if you could tell me where I might see some error messages - does mysql have logs that would point out errors.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: hard to tell without knowing any details... when you say doesn't work, what exactly doesn't work? does tomcat start? is you app not deploying? can you get to the default tomcat page?

Comment: Sorry when I say it doesn't work, I mean that my application is not reading the database. But I have replicated the DB exactly on the server, so some kind of config issues exists.

Comment: I am using a java web application on Tomcat - sorry should have stated that from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does have logs which can help find the solution, but I suspect the issue is in the code. Have you added logging and/or error catching in your code?

Answer (score 1):

One thing to consider is that MySQL table name references are case sensitive on non-Windows platforms.